# Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2 during Scrapy install

Tags: cmd, scrapy, admin

I've been looking through endless forums trying to solve this and I still haven't found an answer that works. I'm new to windows and I'm trying to set things up as I have them on my Mac but the Command Line is presented challenges (what's the equivalent to sudo?) eg, on mac I would type 'sudo pip install scrapy', what's the equivalent on windows? I'm getting this error below and I cannot seem to find my way around it. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

```
  C:\Users\kenma\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Users\\kenma\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    creating users
    creating users\kenma
    creating users\kenma\appdata
    creating users\kenma\appdata\local
    creating users\kenma\appdata\local\temp
    C:\Users\kenma\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /Tcc:\users\kenma\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitdw65bp.c /Fousers\kenma\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitdw65bp.obj
    xmlXPathInitdw65bp.c
    c:\users\kenma\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitdw65bp.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\kenma\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kenma\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-c6lrhk\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kenma\appdata\local\temp\pip-vhli1l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\kenma\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-c6lrhk\lxml\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to `lxml` installation which is a scrapy dependency.
The official [documentation page](http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation) has some solutions but it recommends to use unofficial binaries for windows operating system which can be found here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml